# JavaScript - Redirecting To Pages According To Value Selected From Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, html

I have two drop down list with selection values. I have done the function part where the selected values from both drop down list will be displayed in the `testPoint.html` page (as shown in the function). Now, I would wanna separate the pages according to the profile selected in the `Profile` drop down list.

For instance, when user selects the 'FULL' option from the drop down list, the page will be redirected to 'testPointDRC.html'

Need help on this one.

```js
(function() {
  function onSubmitClicked(event) {

    var product = document.getElementById('product'),
      productVal = product.value,
      profile = document.getElementById('profile'),
      profileVal = profile.value;
    url = 'testPoint.html?product=' + encodeURIComponent(productVal) + '&profile=' + encodeURIComponent(profileVal);
    location.href = url;

    if (profileVal = "Full DRC") {
      url = "testPointDRC.asp";
    }
  }

  var submitButton = document.getElementById('btngo');
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', onSubmitClicked);
})();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>Choose a Product &nbsp: </h4>

      <select id="product"> 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
      <br><br>

      <h4>Choose a Profile &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp: </h4>
      <select id="profile"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="TEST PROFILES">
 <option value = "Full">FULL</option>
 <option value = "QC">QC</option>
 <option value = "Cold">COLD</option>
 <option value = "Hot">HOT</option>
 <option value = "Room">ROOM</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" class="button button2" />
```

Comment: use the window object and set `window.location.href` equal to the redirect url.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I have plenty of selections where various pages needed to be redirected to. `if and else` condition is what I need. Thanks again, bud ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took your idea and created below codes using `JQuery` and pure `JavaScript`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btngo').on('click', function() {
    var profile = $('.profile').find('option:selected').val(),
      prod = $('.product').find('option:selected').val(),
      url;

    switch (profile) {

      case 'Full':
        url = "testPointFULL.asp?product=" + prod + "&profile=" + profile;
        break;

      case 'QC':
        url = "testPointQC.asp?product=" + prod + "&profile=" + profile;
        break;

      case 'Cold':
        url = "testPointCOLD.asp?product=" + prod + "&profile=" + profile;
        break;

      case 'Hot':
        url = "testPointHOT.asp?product=" + prod + "&profile=" + profile;
        break;

      case 'Room':
        url = "testPointROOM.asp?product=" + prod + "&profile=" + profile;
        break;

      default:
        alert("No option like this");
    }
    if (prod !== "NONE" && profile !== "NONE") {
      window.open(url);
      alert(url);
      $(this).submit();
    } else {
      alert('Selection was not correct');
    }

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Choose a Product:</h4>
<select class="product">
  <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
    <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<h4>Choose a Profile : </h4>
<select class="profile">
  <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
    <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="TEST PROFILES">
    <option value="Full">FULL</option>
    <option value="QC">QC</option>
    <option value="Cold">COLD</option>
    <option value="Hot">HOT</option>
    <option value="Room">ROOM</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br><br>
<input type="button" id="btngo" value="Go" class="button button2" />
```

Pure JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("prod").addEventListener("submit", openNew);

function openNew() {
  var prod = document.getElementById("product"),
    prodSel = prod.options[prod.selectedIndex].value,
    prof = document.getElementById("profile"),
    profSel = prof.options[prof.selectedIndex].value,
    url;

  // alert(profSel);

  switch (profSel) {

    case 'Full':
      url = "testPointFULL.asp?product=" + prodSel + "&profile=" + profSel;
      break;

    case 'QC':
      url = "testPointQC.asp?product=" + prodSel + "&profile=" + profSel;
      break;

    case 'Cold':
      url = "testPointCOLD.asp?product=" + prodSel + "&profile=" + profSel;
      break;

    case 'Hot':
      url = "testPointHOT.asp?product=" + prodSel + "&profile=" + profSel;
      break;

    case 'Room':
      url = "testPointROOM.asp?product=" + prodSel + "&profile=" + profSel;
      break;

    default:
      alert("No option like this");
  }

  if (prodSel !== "NONE" && profSel !== "NONE") {
    window.open(url);
    alert(url);
  } else {
    alert('Selection was not correct');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="prod">
  <h4>Choose a Product:</h4>
  <select id="product">
    <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
      <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
      <option value="test">Test</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>

  <h4>Choose a Profile : </h4>
  <select id="profile">
    <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
      <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="TEST PROFILES">
      <option value="Full`">FULL</option>
      <option value="QC">QC</option>
      <option value="Cold">COLD</option>
      <option value="Hot">HOT</option>
      <option value="Room">ROOM</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" class="button button2" />
</form>
```

I just added the `alert()` to show you it works for some reason the snippet doesn't show the redirect.

Any ways here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/93bc7Lc5/) that works.

Pure JavaScript [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/7pm787s2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback and your time. Really do appreciate it but I would prefer to use JavaScript over jQuery. Thanks a lot once again ! :)

Comment: @xerxes39 Well don't know why you really want to stick with `JavaScript` created a script with pure `JavaScript` the script have an Even listener which is listing to the 'submit' event which will call the function when it hears the "submit" event.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. I can't seem to put in many conditions, it directs to only one page.

Comment: 1 page ? what you are there any other than the one you have mentioned ? ok hold on

Comment: My question was regarding redirecting the pages. When user selects any value from the drop down list, it will redirect to the respective page. For example, if i choose QC from the drop down list, i will be redirected to `testPointQC.asp' page. When user selects 'Full', it will redirect to the page `testPointFull.asp`.

Comment: @xerxes39 Updated the `JavaScript` part used a `switch ... case` to switch the URL and the page according to the profile selection. Will update the `JQuery` as well.

Comment: @xerxes39 All the codes have been updated to match you question check and let me know if my answer helped or not.

Comment: Oh pheww. THANKS A BUNCH, MAN ! This is what exactly I wanted. `Swicth Case` seem to be much easier than `if and else` in this situation. Thanks loads man !

Comment: NP happy to help. And yes you can use an `if ... else` but that's very cumbersome using a `switch ... case` makes it easy in coding and when mantling. Keep in mind the key words are case sensitive so you have to have the exact word you have as the value in the case loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will take all these in, thanks a bunch for the advice.  Really appreciate it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Place your `location.href = url` to after checking the condition.

```
 url = some_url;
 If(condition){
   url= new_url;
 }
 location.href=url;
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Hi sir. This method seem to work only for one condition. I am unable to use `else if` or few `if` as it will only be redirected to only the same page.

Comment: You can assign the url to the variable inside conditional  statement. Then before the function end use ` location.href = url`.